# Installing Home-brew on mac-os

Tags: macos, themes, shopify, homebrew, liquid

Hello I have a problem when I try to install home-brew on my mac os laptop M1 CHIP when install it everything goes fine however there a weird step I Have to do in-order for to complete the installation. this is what it says in the terminal

'''
==> Next steps:

- Add Homebrew to your PATH in /Users/wessammontasser/.zprofile:
  echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/wessammontasser/.zprofile
  eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation:
  https://docs.brew.sh
  '''

What I am trying to do is install theme kit for Shopify theme development

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your terminal and launch :

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/wessammontasser/.zprofile eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

But according to the official documentation (https://brew.sh/index_fr), you just need to launch one line :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```